# Who was the man of the series for the India vs New Zealand test match series 2014?

Tags: cricket, awards

I want to know who got the man of the series award for the India vs New Zealand test match series 2014.

I can't find that in [cricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/new-zealand-v-india-2014/engine/match/667653.html).

Comment: It might be Mccullum.

Comment: Both the man of the match for 2nd test as well as man of the series was Mccullum

Comment: McCullum scored a double century in the first test, and a NZ record 302 in the second of the two test series. Man of the Series is rather an understatement, I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [BCCI.TV](http://www.bcci.tv/match/nz-ind-2014/07) Brendon McCullum was declared man of the series. Go to *Match Home* tab -> In the commentary box, search for "Man of the Series".

Here it is clearly written: "**Man of the Series**: Brendon McCullum". See the screenshot here.

[image: Man of the Series:]

Comment: Will you please point me to that please...i am trying to find but couldn't

Comment: @Jatin - As I have pointed in the answer Go to the `Match Home` tab -> Here in the `Match stream` you can see "**Man of the Series**: Brendon McCullum" See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

They have not awarded a man of the series award.
Look at the commentary of awards presentation. Only MoM is awarded. http://www.espncricinfo.com/new-zealand-v-india-2014/engine/match/667653.html?innings=4;page=2;view=commentary

Comment: Ya, they havent awarded Man of the Series award source: http://www.bcci.tv/match/nz-ind-2014/07